# Insufficient Prilivege for Function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions

I'm using a Function that I can't read, when I try to open it, I can't see the definition.
I get following error

> Error : Insufficient privilege.

Nevertheless, it is being executed by my app without any issue, but I would like to export my app to another server and I can't export this function.

How should I do to be able to read it ?

Comment: You'll need to use an account with sufficient privileges.  Please post the *complete* error message, including any codes.

Answer (score 2):

By default the DEFINER is the only user that can read stored programs. If DEFINER is left out then the default user that is created the function is used. This is a security feature.

Definer and invoker security contexts differ as follows:

A stored program or view that executes in definer security context executes with the privileges of the account named by its DEFINER attribute. These privileges may be entirely different from those of the invoking user. The invoker must have appropriate privileges to reference the object (for example, EXECUTE to call a stored procedure or SELECT to select from a view), but when the object executes, the invoker's privileges are ignored and only the DEFINER account privileges matter. If this account has few privileges, the object is correspondingly limited in the operations it can perform. If the DEFINER account is highly privileged (such as a root account), the object can perform powerful operations no matter who invokes it.

A stored routine or view that executes in invoker security context can perform only operations for which the invoker has privileges. The DEFINER attribute can be specified but has no effect for objects that execute in invoker context.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-security.html